# implementing Navigator.serial in Angular

Tags: angular, interface, serial-port, webapi, navigator

I have the problem that in my Angular app the error
**Property 'serial' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.**
get.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kf19n7?file=src/app/app.component.ts

The app works in local mode. To fix this error I have to integrate serial into the Navigator interface.

https://wicg.github.io/serial/

can someone please help me how to do this ?

My attempts unfortunately show errors

```
interface Navigator extends MSFileSaver,..... {

readonly Serial: serial; }
```

Thanks :)

***EDIT: solved***

I Edited the Stackblitz files.

Comment: Interface NavigatorWithSerial extends Navigator?

Comment: Sorry, I do not really understand your answer.

Comment: Thanks, awesome!! Maybe you could respond the question with the link and mark it as answer: it is hard to see that this has been solved on stackblitz. Also I had to add `filters` option in SerialOptions [see docs](https://wicg.github.io/serial/#requestport-method)

Answer (score 5):

The type information for navigator.serial is available from DefinitelyTyped as [dom-serial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dom-serial)

```
npm install --save-dev @types/dom-serial
```